# Swift: unable to serialize Json response

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, nsurl, nsjsonserialization, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm making a http request using sessions. Here is my code:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
    (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print(error?.description)
    } else {
        do {
            print("data recived : \(data)")
             let jsonContent = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            print("json content: \(jsonContent)")
        }catch{

        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

When I print the data response I get this:

```
data recived : Optional(<OS_dispatch_data: data[0x1245c9d60] = { composite, size = 41479, num_records = 3 record[0] = { from = 0, length = 9580, data_object = 0x124584720 }, record[1] = { from = 0, length = 10846, data_object = 0x1245c9a00 }, record[2] = { from = 0, length = 21053, data_object = 0x1245c9f60 }, }>)
```

Any of you knows the NSJSONSerialization is not working?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: It looks like you're receiving data; what value were you expecting in jsonContent?

Comment: @Kevin, yes I'm expecting Json Data

Comment: Can you clarify which error you're getting back? Add `print(error)` in the catch block

Comment: NSJSONSerialization is for JSON. `<OS_dispatch_data: data[0x1245c9d60] = { composite, size = ...` is *not* JSON.

Answer (score -1):

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(URL, completionHandler: {(data, reponse, error) in

let jsonResults : AnyObject

do {
        jsonResults = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
      // success ...
  } 
 catch let error as NSError {
      // failure
      print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

})

task.resume()
```